# When I deploy my .NET Web Application to my server and try to run it I get an assembly error

Tags: asp.net, .net, security, web, .net-assembly

Assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is a conditionally APTCA assembly which is not enabled in the current AppDomain.  To enable this assembly to be used by partial trust or security transparent code, please add assembly name 'System.Web.Extensions, PublicKey=0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100B5FC90E7027F67871E773A8FDE8938C81DD402BA65B9201D60593E96C492651E889CC13F1415EBB53FAC1131AE0BD333C5EE6021672D9718EA31A8AEBD0DA0072F25D87DBA6FC90FFD598ED4DA35E44C398C454307E8E33B8426143DAEC9F596836F97C8F74750E5975C64E2189F45DEF46B2A2B1247ADC3652BF5C308055DA9' to the the PartialTrustVisibleAssemblies list when creating the AppDomain.

Comment: Sometimes the error message is not very useful and not enough knowledge is the real issuse! Microsoft really needs better software aka Visual Studio

Answer (score 1):

If you have trust in web.config remove it.

You may have some references pointing to .NET 4.5 when they should be .NET 4.0